# Configure a stage in an Azure DevOps pipeline to be manual, not automatic

Tags: triggers, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have an Azure DevOps pipeline that first builds a Function App and then deploys it through several different stages. My goal is not have the deployment stages trigger automatically.

When using releases, I'm able to achieve my goal by defining pre-deployment checks so that deployment to a stage is not triggered automatically. Since there is no option to make deployment of a stage 'manual after stage', I have to add an artefact filter to the relevant stage and set it to exclude `*`.

Unfortunately, stage triggers and artefact filters don't appear to exist for pipelines -

- [YAML schema reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/yaml-schema?view=azure-devops)

The environments that I can link to deployment stages do include approvals and checks, but these appear to be very limited and of no real use.

- [Define approvals and checks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass)

  > Currently, manual approval and evaluate artifact are the only available checks

I have attempted to add a manual intervention, but despite the task being available through the pipeline assistant it does not work on a pipeline, only on a release.

- [Manual Intervention task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/manual-intervention?view=azure-devops)

  > This task is supported only in classic release pipelines.

How can I achieve my goal of manual deployment to stages of a pipeline?

Here is an example of my pipeline.

```
stages:
- stage: Publish
  displayName: Publish Function App
  jobs:
  - ...
- stage: Dev
  displayName: Deploy Dev
  jobs:
  - ...
- stage: Staging
  displayName: Deploy Staging
  jobs:
  - ...
- stage: Production
  displayName: Deploy Production
  jobs:
  - ...
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I achieve my goal of manual deployment to stages of a
>   pipeline?

Sorry but as I know manual trigger for yaml pipeline is not available currently. [This feature request](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/629260/specify-manual-stages-in-multi-stage-yaml-pipeline.html) has been submitted to our User Voice forum. You can vote it and track the issue there, so that you'll get notifications if there's any update.

According to your scenario, have you tried the [approvals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#approvals)? If we set the approvals in `Environments`, the deployment job would stop and wait for manual approvals. The deployment to a stage won't really start until we manually approve that, I think it's also helpful for your scenario. Here's [one blog](https://devkimchi.com/2019/10/02/azure-devops-multi-stage-pipelines-approval-strategies/) which you can refer to.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have added my up vote to the user voice. I have looked at the approvals, but this would mean that everyone who should be able to manually promote will get an email every time one person wants to do so. I think it would be very confusing and very prone to error. I believe you can only have each stage waiting once too, so if `build.1` has stage `B` waiting for approval, approval requests will not be set for `build.1` stage `B`.

Comment: I have looked at the `Branch control` check, but unfortunately this simply fails the pipeline if the check fails, rather than stopping the pipeline to allow for future manual trigger.

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience. Have voted up for the issue also, hope the feature could come true soon :)